# stretching link throughout entire <li>

Tags: html, css

the text within the li is a link, where as the entire li item including the text should work as a link. How can I get it so that the entire li item operates as link as opposed to just the text within the li?

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(http://iforce.co.nz/i/chiislxt.mp4.png);
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul li {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

#navbar a:link {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: black;
    font-family: Franklin Gorthic Heavy, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #003300;
    color: gold;
}

#navbar a:visited {
    color: black;
}

a:active {
    background-color: #003300; 
    color: gold;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reading">READING</a></li>
            <li><a href="#store">STORE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here's a screenshot for reference: (home has my cursor over)

[image]
Cheers

Comment: @PaperThick - Horrible suggestion and invalid HTML.

Comment: Btw, made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3SUFJ/1/ @Ari: some people seem more willing to answer a question if you make it as easy as possible, my advice is to always include a jsfiddle with a minimal example (if possible).

Comment: I tried my answer below in your fiddle - it works.

Comment: btw, this question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264370/stretching-a-tag-to-fill-entire-li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You then should move some of the li css to the a css - like so

```
#navbar ul li {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;

}

#navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
   padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a quick example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/DFS5P/

Comment: It's a suggestion. There is no need to define **float** in 'anchor' because you already define float to LI & if you define **float** then there is no need for 'display:inline-block'

Comment: @sandeep - That was just because I've ran into problems in the past with older browsers when float wasn't defined on the a tag as well as the LI element. Just trying to cover all the bases :)

Answer (score 1):

Give your `padding` & `height` to **anchor** instead of **LI**. Write like this:

```
#navbar ul li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DFS5P/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
width:100%;
```

to:

```
#navbar ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the padding from the list items and give them a fixed width, it works as you need.

```
#navbar ul li {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RtmXs/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is definately not the best way, but sometimes I just move the entire 'li' inside the 'a' tag. This way everything witin the 'li' goes to the link in  when you click on it.

Works fine by me, but as I said it is not the best way.