# Completely linkable li element

Tags: javascript, html, css, webbrowser-control

I need to make linkable an entire `<li>` or `<tr>` element, someone suggest me to use javascript, with an onclick action.

```
    function doNav(url)
    {
        document.location.href = url;
    }
```

This do the job, the problem is that, in this way is impossible for the user, understand what url is going to. How to realize my need (completly clickable elements) without changing browser behaviour?

Comment: Why not just use an `<a>` tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264370/stretching-a-tag-to-fill-entire-li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this.  Add this css

```
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;//more or less, to suit your needs
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will make the entire `<li>` containing an anchor clickable

Comment: Shouldn't you use inline-block then?

Comment: Doh! the perils of high technology:)

Comment: @Spatie, what inline elements do you want to preserve?

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="block"><a href="whatever">Text</a></li>
```

That lets you see the target. And then:

```
.block{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none; //just so it isn't underlined
}
```

in the CSS will take care of the "whole thing needs to be clickable" problem.

Comment: @Mariano oh right, the whole `<li>` needs to be clickable. Forgot about that part. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="anchors" title="click me I am a link" > link 1 </li>
 <li class="anchors" title="click me I am a link" > link 1 </li>
 <li class="anchors" title="click me I am a link" > link 1 </li>
 <li class="anchors" title="click me I am a link" > link 1 </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li.anchors{
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:blue;
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin:2px 4px;
 padding: 2px 4px;
}

ul li.anchors:hover{
 color:navy;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

better way may be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/iamanubhavsaini/Cv2FM/1/

here, use `content` property and `data-` attribute to tell user before hand as what they are going to click on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/iamanubhavsaini/Cv2FM/ and http://jsfiddle.net/iamanubhavsaini/Cv2FM/1/