# Javascript isn't working because two scripts won't work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu-item.true, #globallogo").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

And I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.menu-item > a').attr('target', '_parent');
});
```

Because of some reason the two scripts won't work together, is there a way to solve this?

This is my menu ,maybe it's helpful for a solution:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting and what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: Why should you want to run the first piece of code?

Comment: Because than you get: <li onclick="window.location etc."></li>

Comment: So it will make the li clickable

Comment: Couldn't you just use CSS to have the `a` fill the entire `li` making the whole thing clickable?

Comment: @haxtbh What i want is that: the <li> get clickable and the <a> get a 'target="_parent"'

Comment: @jk how can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264370/stretching-a-tag-to-fill-entire-li

Comment: ul li > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

Comment: How is it not working? What happens when you click either `li` or `a`?

Answer (score -1):

You do not have a `<script>` tag for your second bit of code. All javascript needs to be in a `<script>` tag or in a .js file linked to using another `<script>` tag.