# Use Datatables only in abstract?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an X-Y problem that I'm looking to be set straight on.

My X is that I'd like to query a database and initiate a download of the returned data on the clientside. I've got the querying down pat, no issue there. I can get the data to the client with no issues. My issue is with the downloading of the data once it's in the webpage.

My Y is that I'd like to do this by abusing [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

I am working on a node.js project which uses DataTables in one part of the project. It's wonderful, I'm very appreciative. It takes in data, displays a table, very good.

I'd like to know if the following is possible:

In another part of the project I merely want to display a "download" button, which launches the Ajax to fetch data from the server, and then initiates a download on the user's browser.

I was wondering, **because I already serve the DataTables dependency as part of the page, is it possible load a datatable without displaying it, and only display the [csv button](https://datatables.net/reference/button/csv), extended with custom text?**

---

Why I think this is worthwhile:

- I am much more confident in the download functionality already built into DataTables than I would be manually implementing a method to serve this purpose.
- It would keep the codebase that much more clean and readable, assuming that this is relatively simple. No need complicating things with a failure-prone download function when a perfectly good one exists in a dependancy.
- I'd like to avoid sending more code to the client than
- It would also be a neat hack, if that's not purpose enough.

---

For a bit more context, here's some of the index.ejs page:

```
<ul class="menu custom-descriptor">
    <li class="menu-item view-table"><i class="ignore click icon table"></i> View Table <i class="icon right angle"></i></li>
    <li class="menu-item download"><i class="ignore click icon table"></i> Download <i class ="icon down angle"></i></li>
</ul>
```

and here's some of the JavaScript that powers it (with the offending portion marked with a `???`):

```
// OnClick listener:
$('.menu-item').on('click', function(e){
  let item = e.target;
  let classes = item.classList
  let parentClasses = item.parentElement.classList

  if(classes.contains('context-disabled'))     { return; }

  else if(classes.contains('view-table') && parentClasses.contains('custom-descriptor')) { displayTableHandler(); }
  else if(classes.contains('download') && parentClasses.contains('custom-descriptor')) { downloadDataHandler(); }
});


// handler:
function downloadDataHandler() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    //...
    success: function(response){
      // ???
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible. Here is a general solution followed by links to sources with more detailed information:

- Initialize the DataTable object on a table with the `display: none` style attribute. This will keep the table, in its entirety, hidden from view.
- In order to display the buttons, make use of the [direct insertion](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#Direct-insertion) portion of the Buttons documentation. Style as appropriate. If within an li, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264370/stretching-a-tag-to-fill-entire-li) may be of use.
- use the [button.trigger()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/button().trigger()) method in order to avoid the user having to click the button once to prepare it, and another time to download it.

In the end your HTML and then handler may look like:

```
<ul class="menu custom-descriptor">
    <li class="menu-item view-table"><i class="ignore click icon table"></i> View in Table <i class="icon right angle"></i></li>
    <li class="menu-item download"><i class="ignore click icon table"></i> Download <i class ="icon down angle"></i></li>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <table id="views" class="ui celled table">
            <thead id="views-head"></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>>
    </div>
</ul>
```

```
function downloadDataHandler() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    //...
    success: function(response){
      // build out DataTable data
      table = $("#views").DataTable({
        // data, etc
        buttons:[
            {
              extend: 'csv',
              text: '<i class=\"ignore click icon table\"></i> Download <i class =\"icon down angle\"></i>'
            }
          ]
        });
      let button = table.buttons().container()[0].childNodes[0];
      button.classList.//remove and add as needed for styling
      $(".download").replaceWith(button);

      table.button().trigger();

    }
  });
}
```

other sources: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/62163