# How to completely remove bullet from UL, when making button

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Very new to coding, I'm having an issue. I want to turn my list that is used in my header into buttons. However, even though I set ul to list-style-type: none; the area where the bullet was seems to still be there, because when I go to make a button that area has the border applied to it.

If you need any more information please let me know!

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 0.05em dotted #35b8b1;
  margin: 1em;
  /* text-decoration: none; */
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="button" href="#HTML">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#CSS">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="#JS">JS</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please user proper formatting by sending code as code blocks, not as images. This helps us to diagnose and help you with the problem that you are facing.

Comment: You HTML is not valid., move the start of the anchor INSIDE the LIs - I made you a snippet with the correct format

Comment: Perhaps you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264370/stretching-a-tag-to-fill-entire-li